# Laravel form creation exposes schema

Tags: security, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel, i am creating a form to create a new record in database. In my controller, i am saving input data to database directly by using `Input::all()`. So, for this to work; i am creating form elements with same names as database fields;

```
{{ Form::label('name', 'Project Name:') }}
{{ Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

So, if someone looks at the output html, it is very easy to guess the `project` table and the fields within the table.

What i would like to know is: Is this normal practice? Is it okay to implement this? What are Laravel experts using as the best practice for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

with laravel there is no problem if someone knows the name of your fields, in each form laravel create a hidden field that contain a token so not anyone can send post requests to you site